# How to represent circuit in state space

Tags: control-system

I have this circuit and I must represent it in state space. I know the process because I have done similar ones but having trouble with this one. I have found the Kirchhoff equations for the 2 loops and for the upper junction, whatever I do after that I can't end up with two equations x'1 and x'2.

- First loop: V(t)=V(R1)+V(c1)+V(R2)
- Second loop: V(R3)+V(c2)=V(R2)+V(c1)
- Junction: i(t)=i(R3)+i(c1) or i(t)=i(c2)+i(R2) => i(c1)=i(R3)+i(t) and i(c2)=i(R2)+i(t)

I know that V(C1)=x1 ,and V(c2)=x2 and i(c1)=c1*x'1 , i(c2)=c2*x'2

Whatever replacements I cant find X'1=V(c1)+V(C2)+V(t) and X'2=V(C1)+V(C2)+V(t)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's depend on your output y. If you take U = V(t) and Y= Vout = V(R2)+V(C2)=V(R3)+V(C3);
than we have:
dX/dt = A* X + B*U

Y=C*X+D*U
Equations:
V(t) = U = R1*I1+Zeq*I1 with Zeq = (R2+1/JC1W)//(R3+1/JC2W)
Y(t) = Vout = Zeq *I1
Y(t)/U(t)= Zeq/(Zeq+R1)
Y(t)/U(t) = 1/(R1/Zeq+1)
Y(t) + (R1/Zeq+1) * Y(t) = U(t) with s=jw;
you will get dY/dt = A* Y(t) + B* U(t)
and Y(t) = C* Y(t) with C =1 (first order).

Comment: Thanks for answering, dont I need to find two equations X'1=Ax+Bu and X'2=Ax+Bu ?

Comment: In this case you have the state variable X equal to Y (one parameter) not a matrix (first order system).

Comment: Ok thank you, one last thing, I forgot to mention that my exercise sais that my output is the capacitor C2(as diagram) does this change anything?

Comment: Yes its change, because now you have:     Vc2 = Zc2/(R3+Zc2)*Y with Y=Vout= V(R2)+V(C2)

Comment: I thought my Vout would be only Vout=VC2.. Why is it Y=Vout= V(R2)+V(C2)

Comment: Also I dont have the value for I1

Comment: You don't need the value of I1 (its a representation), all that you have to do, is to calculate in the same way that i show you before with Vout = Vc2, you can use the same equations before with X= V(R3)+V(C2) and Y = V(C2, i can't give you all the equations, you have to dig the solution by your self, i show the way to do....

Comment: Oh nice, thank you again!! So to end this, my input is V(t) = U = R1*I1+Zeq*I1, my output is Y = V(C2) but where do I use this X= V(R3)+V(C2)?

Comment: Yes and you have VC2 = Y = Zc2/(R3+Zc2)*X.

Comment: codo isn't there a way to solve it with Kirchhoff equtations? I cant solve it with your way :(